# Div moving towards left on screen resize

Tags: html, css

I am working on website http://torquebranding.com/ , Images under THE PROCESS sections transferring to left as soon as screen resized.

I tried

```
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto
```

to make it center aligned , but failed.

Any suggestions ?

Thanks

Comment: You are required to post your markup that shows the problem here, not your web site which will change or disappear altogether helping no one in the future! [mcvd]

Answer (score 1):

You have this rule in your css.  If you override it or remove it, the images are centered

```
processTabs {
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

Here are before and after pictures - see the processTabs rule in the dev tools side bar.  In the before picture, the class is checked and in the after the class is disabled.

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Comment: Removed , Still sasme

Comment: [Do not post images of code or errors!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714)

Answer (score 0):

Your page is using different media styles with different page sizes.
For example, I have changed .processTabs added margin in media version 1.0.0.193. It works. Also, it is always good to use percentage instead of using px.

```
.processTabs { margin: 0 -2%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

(sorry, had an error due to copying in there - edited... -> 0px )

This rule:

```
.processTabs
{
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

is included as an inline style (maybe added dynamically by some plugin or framework) in your HTML document, on line 689. This causes the problem you wrote about in the question. To fix it, remove that rule, or if can't do that (because of some plugin adding it) overwrite it with the following in your stylesheet:

```
.processTabs
{
    margin-left: 0px !important;
}
```